# Mathjax problem

Tags: support, status-norepro

This just popped up when I loaded the main page:
[image: Mathjax problem]

I know the site uses a script on the "public" server or have they downgraded to a stable version due to other problems.

Comment: I saw this message yesterday and assumed it was a change in how mathjax was handled but I am interested to see if they can resolve it.

Comment: I also saw the message yesterday evening.  Clearing my cache seemed to fix it.  LaTeX rendered properly before, during, and after the message appeared.

Comment: This stuff is consistently reproduced on the default browser in Android (HTC Desire S device). And it's rather annoying - it blocks the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this at the moment.  It could have been a temporary network issue or you may have had a stale cache - please keep us posted if it happens again.

Comment: I see it reproed consistently on questions using Mathjax when opened from Android default browser.